# How to generically handle test assertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I would like to log all assertions when unit testing  without being too code intrusive.
Ideally I would like a way to hook any test assertion like Assert.IsTrue and if it fails then log the assertion and message to my application's log (using log4net).

Logging is especially useful in parallel testing scenarios. Unless I used a try catch throw for each test I cant see a way to do it - too much code bloat?

I am sure many people have a similar requirement.
I am using the latest Visual Studio 17 and Resharper
MSTestV2 test framework and adaptor v1.4.0.
Any ideas? Am I missing the obvious?

Thanks in advance
Kind regards
Terry

Comment: Technically, mstest unit test failures are raised as `AssertFailedException` exceptions so you just need a way to catch this exception before the unit test runner.

Comment: Depending on the scenario, what you might want to do is write a [logger extension for vstest](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/report.md). However I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what the purpose is here. The testing framework will handle any failed assertion and log it. Do you want to see passed assertions as well or something else?

Comment: ah right - the purpose is this: I am using a fairly detailed log in my application to help with debugging (especially the multi threaded bits). I like logs - I can search, filter and diff them to get at hard to find issues. When I raise my own app based run-time assertions they are logged usually by a try catch/throw handler or a top-level run loop. All I would do is log the test assertions to the same log file. So when I diff the logs I can see exactly where the the test failed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are some libraries which can have assert with loggers out-of-the-box, but if you just want to do it yourself, instead of writing try catch for every test, you can use method which accept action as a parameter. This action can accept any assert methods.

Something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        AssertLogger.AssertWithLogs(() => Assert.IsTrue(false));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        AssertLogger.AssertWithLogs(() => Assert.IsTrue(false));
    }
}

public static class AssertLogger
{
    public static void AssertWithLogs(Action assert)
    {
        try {
            assert();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Use log4net or other loggers
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting! Yes, exactly my point: I don't want huge code bloat with cumbersome try catch throw obscuring the essence of the test. 
I am surprised this sort of thing is not available as a hook in the main test engine run loop.

Comment: I will have a bash with this thank you - for me ideally its still a bit long and invasive - ideally I would have thought there is a way to hook the underlying assert.xxx process

Comment: Mike has got an interesting point also: I think this would work - I could use it merge the Test output with my log4net log. mmm need to get a handle on writing a 'nugget' then!